# Where can I find the original Arabic text of this narration by Ibn Mas'ud?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, uloom-al-hadith

I need the original Arabic text of the following narration:-

Ibn Mas'ud used to say, "When you bless the Prophet, then make the prayer on him excellent. You do not know; perhaps it will be shown to him. Say, ‘O Allah, bestow  your mercy and your blessing on the Master of the Messengers, the Imam of the God-fearing, the Leader of the Good and the Messenger of Mercy.’"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The english translation you have quoted seems close to Aisha Bewley's [translation](https://archive.org/details/muhammad-messenger-of-allah-ash-shifa-of-qadi-iyad/page/n225/mode/2up) of [Ash-Shifa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Shifa_bi_Ta%27rif_Huquq_al-Mustafa) of Qadi 'Iyad, the Arabic text of which can be found [here](https://shamela.ws/book/23645/905#p1).

The narration is found in [Sunan Ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1309580) in كتاب إقامة الصلاة والسنة فيها in the chapter باب الصلاة على النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم the Arabic text of this part is as follows:

> عن عبد الله بن مسعود، قال: إذا صليتم على رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم، فأحسنوا الصلاة عليه، فإنكم لا تدرون، لعل ذلك يعرض عليه، قال: فقالوا له: فعلمنا، قال، قولوا: اللهم اجعل صلاتك، ورحمتك، وبركاتك على سيد المرسلين، وإمام المتقين، وخاتم النبيين، محمد عبدك ورسولك، إمام الخير، وقائد الخير، ورسول الرحمة

Comment: Thank you so much!